# Removing Duplicates with SQL Express 2017

Tags: sql-server

I have a table of 120 million rows. About 8 million of those rows are duplicates depending on what value/column I use to determine duplicates. For argument sake, I'm testing out the email column vs multiple columns to see what happens with my data.

The file is about 10GB, so I cannot simply add another table to the database because of the size limits of SQL Express. Instead, I thought I'd try to extract, truncate, insert using a temp table since I've been meaning to try that method out.

I know I can use CTE to remove the duplicates, but every single time I try to do that it takes forever and my system locks up. My solution is to do the following.

```
1.Extract all rows to tempdb
2.Sort by Min(id)
3.Truncate original table
4.Transfer new unique data from tempdb back to main table
5.Take the extra duplicates and trim to uniques using Delimit
6.Import the leftover rows back into the database.
```

My table looks like the following.

```
Name    Gender   Age   Email              ID
Jolly   Female   28    jolly@jolly.com    1
Jolly   Female   28    jolly@jolly.com    2
Jolly   Female   28    jolly@jolly.com    3
Kate    Female   36    kate@kate.com      4
Kate    Female   36    kate@kate.com      5
Kate    Female   36    kate@kate.com      6
Jack    Male     46    jack@jack.com      7
Jack    Male     46    jack@jack.com      8
Jack    Male     46    jack@jack.com      9
```

My code

```
SET IDENTITY_INSERT test.dbo.contacts ON
GO

select name, gender, age, email, id into ##contacts
from test.dbo.contacts
WHERE id IN
(SELECT MIN(id) FROM test.dbo.contacts GROUP BY name)
TRUNCATE TABLE test.dbo.contacts
INSERT INTO test.dbo.contacts
SELECT name, gender, age, total_score, id
from ##students

SET IDENTITY_INSERT test.dbo.contactsOFF
GO
```

This code is almost working, except for the following error that I see. 
"An explicit value for the identity column in table 'test.dbo.contacts' can only be specified when a column list is used and IDENTITY_INSERT is ON.

I have absolutely no idea why I keep seeing that message since I turned identity_insert on and off.

Can somebody please tell me what I'm missing in the code? And if anybody has another solution to keep unique rows I'd love to hear about it.

Comment: Add a column list for the insert statement.
INSERT INTO test.dbo.contacts(name, gender, age, total_score, id)

Comment: Try to specify the column list after the table (test.dbo.contacts) in your code.

Comment: what's column order in table.

Comment: A CTE is still going to be much faster than this. Trying to `INSERT` everything into a (Global) Temporary Table, and then  re-inserting is going to awfully costly. What was the query you wrote for the CTE? Have you considered deleting in batches?

Comment: I am not sure why you think inserting 112 million rows is going to have less of an impact on your system than deleting 8 million, but it won't. It will be worse. If I were doing this, I would perform the operation in batches, i.e. Identify all 8 million records to be deleted, but then delete them 100,000 rows at a time.

Comment: really complicated thinking here. Use a "row_count over the fields which have to be equal" delete all rows having a row_number>1 using the primary key.

Comment: @BerndOtt, you missed the part where he says that "I know I can use CTE to remove the duplicates, but every single time I try to do that it takes forever and my system locks up"

Comment: @ildanny row_number is not a cte. It's part of the ranking functions. cte's are used to resolve trees or something equal. I provided a answer, as you can see no "with" is used.

Comment: @BerndOtt: I know that it's not a CTE. CTE is inside the quote, so in the original post. His question is not about how to do it, but how to avoid that it "takes forever and my system locks up".

Comment: Inserting the column names after INSERT INTO did the trick, so thank you @wangguanguo and Abhishek for the advice. To clarify, although I understand the use of CTE, by no means am I an expert. One of my 2018 goals was to learn some new skills to help my business and SQL is a priority.

Answer (score 1):

You said that your original problem was that " it takes forever and my system locks up".
The problem is the amount of time necessary for the operation and the lock escalation to table lock.
My suggestion is to break down the operation so that you delete less than 5000 rows at time. 
I assume you have less than 5000 duplicates for each name.
You can read more about lock escalation here:
https://www.sqlpassion.at/archive/2014/02/25/lock-escalations/
About your problem (identity insert), your script contains at least two errors so I guess it's not the original one, so it hard to say why the original one fails.

```
use test;

if object_ID('dbo.contacts') is not null drop table dbo.contacts;

CREATE TABLE dbo.contacts
(
    id int identity(1,1) primary key clustered, 
    name    nvarchar(50),
    gender  varchar(15),
    age     tinyint,
    email   nvarchar(50),
    TS      Timestamp
)

INSERT INTO [dbo].[contacts]([name],[gender],[age],[email])
VALUES
    ('Jolly','Female',28,'jolly@jolly.com'),
    ('Jolly','Female',28,'jolly@jolly.com'),
    ('Jolly','Female',28,'jolly@jolly.com'),
    ('Kate','Female',36,'kate@kate.com'),
    ('Kate','Female',36,'kate@kate.com'),
    ('Kate','Female',36,'kate@kate.com'),
    ('Jack','Male',46,'jack@jack.com'),
    ('Jack','Male',46,'jack@jack.com'),
    ('Jack','Male',46,'jack@jack.com');

--for the purpose of the lock escalation, I assume you have less then 5.000 duplicates for each single name.
if object_ID('tempdb..#KillList') is not null drop table #KillList;
SELECT KL.*, C.TS
    into #KillList
from 
(
    SELECT [name], min(ID) GoodID       
    from dbo.contacts
    group by name 
    having count(*) > 1
) KL inner join 
    dbo.contacts C
  ON KL.GoodID = C.id

--This has the purpose of testing concurrent updates on relevant rows
--UPDATE [dbo].[contacts] SET Age = 47 where ID=7;
--DELETE [dbo].[contacts] where ID=7;

while EXISTS (SELECT top 1 1 from #KillList)
BEGIN 

    DECLARE @id int; 
    DECLARE @name nvarchar(50);
    DECLARE @TS binary(8);

    SELECT top 1 @id=GoodID, @name=Name, @TS=TS from #KillList;

    BEGIN TRAN
    if exists (SELECT * from [dbo].[contacts] where id=@id and TS=@TS)
    BEGIN 
        DELETE FROM C
        from [dbo].[contacts] C
        where id <> @id and Name = @name;
        DELETE FROM #KillList where Name = @name;
    END
    ELSE 
    BEGIN
        ROLLBACK TRAN;
        RAISERROR('Concurrency error while deleting %s', 16, 1, @name);
        RETURN;
    END 
    commit TRAN;

END 

SELECT * from [dbo].[contacts];
```

Answer (score 1):

I wrote it this way, that you can see the sub results of each query.
The inner sql should not have *, instead use id.

```
delete from [contacts] where id in 
(
    select id from
    (
        select *, ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by name, gender, age, email order by id) as rowid from [contacts]
    ) rowstobedeleted where rowid>1
)
```

If this takes too long/makes much load, you can use `SET ROWCOUNT` to provide smaller chunks, but then you need to run it until nothing is delete anymore.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you need something like this:

```
INSERT INTO test.dbo.contacts (idcol1,col2) 
VALUES (value1,value2)
```

Comment: I miss how this can help J.R.